# How can we call onNewRequest property in onBlur in AutoComplete Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Currently I am using Material-UI and I am using the onNewRequest property in AutoComplete field but the onNewRequest triggers only on Enter or when a value is selected, I wish to call the onNewRequest even when we click outside(i.e. onBlur property). Is this possible?
I need to validate whether a user selects from the autocomplete options else throw an error but if the user enters any value and clicks outside the field he escapes the validation.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';

const colors = [
  'Red',
  'Orange',
  'Yellow',
  'Green',
  'Blue',
  'Purple',
  'Black',
  'White',
];

export default class AutoCompleteExampleControlled extends Component {
  state = {
    errMsgMT: '',
  };


  handleNewRequest = (content, index) => {
    if(index == -1){
     this.setState({errMsgMT : "Error"});
    }
    else{
     this.setState({errMsgMT : "Correct"});
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AutoComplete
          hintText="Type 'r', case insensitive"
          onNewRequest={this.handleNewRequest}
          dataSource={colors}
        />
      </div>
    );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

oKay gUYz: You can also just use the autoSelect prop:

```
autoSelect={true}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onClose`, quoting it directly from doc

> Callback function fired when the menu is closed.

```
import React from 'react';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';

const colors = [
  'Red',
  'Orange',
  'Yellow',
  'Green',
  'Blue',
  'Purple',
  'Black',
  'White',
];

class AutoCompleteExample extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onMenuClose = this.onMenuClose.bind(this);
 }
 onMenuClose() {
   console.log("event captured on clicking outside");
 }
 render() {
  return (
    <AutoComplete
      dataSource={colors}
      onClose={this.onMenuClose}
    />
  )
 }
}

export default AutoCompleteExample;
```

Hope this example helps. Good Luck!